# Raster map & vector boundaryline data for Istanbul, Turkey

Tags: raster, data, vector

I'm looking where I can download background raster map for Istanbul (street map?), and then a boundary line file of the the 39 Districts in Istanbul.  Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use a Basemap as the background layer? (if you are working in ArcGIS).
For the boundary lines it should be also very easy to find that. There are several shapefiles out there, just google for Istanbul shapefiles.